# react native ping all hosts stops when IP is not responding

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

Im trying to ping all LAN hosts on my network to find out which one is alive, to later find a raspberry pi which hosts a web service and the idea os to use my app with the raspberry web service.

So far, I could get this script in react-native retrieve the time in ms for the first IPs if they are responsing. It stops when some IP is unused.

What I need to get is to ping all hosts.

Sometimes I get in the bundler console an error like this:

Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: ping失败
Error: ping失败
    at createErrorFromErrorData (blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:2022:17)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:1974:27
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:2541:18)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:2272:18
    at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:2445:13)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/002b13c9-1cd5-412d-b052-f561e7c876a6:2271:14)
    at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:58

```
import Ping from 'react-native-ping';

function check(ip) {

    return  Ping.start('192.168.0.' + ip);
}

async function lanScan(array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    var ok = await check(item);   
      console.log(ok + " " + item)
  }
  console.log('Done!');
}

var ips = [];
for(var i= 100; i<= 254; i++){

    ips.push(i);
}

lanScan(ips);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check function is returning a `Promise`, but you have no facility setup to handle any errors. So as soon as a ping fails in your loop, then entire function stops running. One way you can ensure each ping is always tested is to wrap your check inside a [`try / catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch). For example:

```
async function lanScan(array) {
  for (const item of array) {
    try {
      var ok = await check(item)  
      console.log(ok + " " + item)
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  console.log('Done!')
}
```

Comment: do you know how can I add a timeout to this function?

Comment: @PabloLionelArturi What do you mean?